# Trying to get property of non-object when using view share in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, view

I have some view like this:

```
return view('admin.users.profile')->with('user',User::find(Auth::user()->id));
```

I decide to user View::Share so i don't have to use with in every view. So i put in my AppServicesProvider like this:

```
    View::share('user',User::find(Auth::user()->id));
```

and it give me an errors:

```
"Trying to get property of non-object"
```

so what can be wrong? i have no problem when i'm using it in my view but using ->with. Thanks.

Comment: you put that where in your AppServiceProvider? by the point `register` and `boot` have ran on that provider that is no session as the middleware stack has not ran.

Comment: yes. i put it in there. so is it any solution how i can get those user?

Comment: i put on boot function

Comment: you can't do it there, there is no session to pull the authenticated user from yet. you don't have access to this until after the request has passed through the 'web' middleware group, particularly the session middleware in that group

Comment: Ah ok then. Thanks for your info. 